# Динамическое программирование. Задача на взвешивание грузика. (Монетки?)

Tags: алгоритм, олимпиада

Вот в чём заключается задача:

```
Есть весы с двумя чашами.

На одной из чаш есть предмет веса G.

Также есть N грузиков.

Вывести одно число – минимальное количество грузиков необходимых для взвешивания.
Если взвесить нельзя, вывести «–1». 

Вся информация вводится с клавиатуры: кол-во грузиков, веса грузиков, предмета.
Грузики можно ставить на любую из двух чаш весов.
```

Сама задача на yandex contest (Дорешивание, надо войти через свой аккаунт): https://contest.yandex.ru/contest/4503/problems/C/

Мне преподаватель подсказала что надо копать в сторону алгоритма с монетками, но я так и не дошёл даже до идеи.

Спасибо.

Comment: Информация касательно самого вопроса должна находиться в вопросе, а не на стороннем сайте. По формулировке задачи. Что подразумевается под "N грузиков": N типов грузиков (например, 1гр., 2гр., 5гр. и т.д.) или N фиксированных грузиков (например, 2 по 1гр., 3 по 2гр. и т.д.)?

Comment: Ссылку на сторонний сайт я дал на случай возникновения вопросов и для доступа к тестирующей системе. Просто N произвольных грузиков, которые могут и повторяться.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Каждая ситуация взвешивания описывается через положение грузиков.

Положение  *i*-го грузика можно описать коэффициентом *c<sub>i</sub>*. Грузик может оказаться в чашке с предметом (**c<sub>i</sub> = -1**), в стороне от весов (**с<sub>i</sub>=0**) и в чашке противовеса (**с<sub>i</sub>=1**).

Решение задачи можно представить в виде уравнения
**∑ c<sub>i</sub>W<sub>i</sub> = G**,
где **W<sub>i</sub>** - веса грузиков,
    **с<sub>i</sub> ∈ {-1, 0, 1}** - неизвестные коэффициенты.

Если уравнение неразрешимо, то и задача тоже.

Если решения есть, то среди них следует выбрать решение с наибольшим количеством нулевых коэффициентов.

Алгоритм "брут форс" для **n** грузиков требует перебора **3<sup>n</sup>** вариантов. В то же время исходная задача является разновидностью задачи о рюкзаке и допускает "жадный" перебор, для чего грузики надо рассматривать в порядке убывания веса, а варианты отбрасывать в том случае, когда сумма оставшихся грузиков не может изменить состояние весов.

**UPD**

Необходимое условие существования решения - чтобы **НОД(W<sub>i</sub>)** был делителем **G**.

Соответствующая проверка - существенная часть решения.

Comment: К сожалению, при N = 6000, брутфорс невозможен :)

Comment: Извините, а откуда берутся эти неизвестные коэффиценты? О о

Comment: @ЕгорЛевоненко Спасибо, конкретизировал ответ.